# Probability of a pen cap to rebound around its head when thrown towards a wall

Tags: probability, probability-theory, kinematics

For the sake of simplicity lets assume that the cap is cylinder whose mass, say $M$, is uniformly distributed. Lets it length be $l$ and radius be $R$. The wall is $d$ distance from the initial point. Say i throw it at an angle **theta**, with its head pointing towards the wall. Obviously $g$ is acting downwards.
What is the probability that whole of it's head hits the wall? Also the probability that the head of the cap hits it at an angle.
(Assume more parameters if needed)

Comment: "Obviously $g$ is acting downwards." That's not obvious. Some times it is convenient to have it act upwards. It may simpliy sign manipulation.

Comment: Is this a mathematics question?

Comment: I don't know, should i ask it on the physics section?

Comment: If the cap is a cylinder, what are you considering to be the "head"?

Comment: Let it be one of its circular face.